# Japanese for "The Narrow Road to the Deep North" (the Richard Flanagan novel)

Tags: translation

Is there a commonly agreed upon title for the Richard Flanagan novel "The Narrow Road to the Deep North" (not the travel diary by Matsuo Bashō, which the novel was named after)?

I've seen both "奥の細道", which is the same as the travel diary the novel was named after, and "ザ・ナロー・ロード・トゥー・ザ・ディープ・ノース", a katakana transliteration of the name of the novel.

Comment: Wow, it seems too new to have an established Japanese title, unless there's a translation already. But I'd be surprised if a publisher titles it "奥の細道", because it's purely English pun on the plot, as far as I can get from the synopsis.

Comment: I'll add another option - the Japanese wiki article on the Booker prize lists it simply as "The Narrow Road to the Deep North, リチャード・フラナガン"

Comment: I bet it will be titled  『ナロー・ロード ～奥の細道～』, like [this](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/404275001X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was published as 『奥のほそ道』 in Japan in 2018.

[Amazon.co.jp - リチャード・フラナガン著『奥のほそ道』](https://amzn.asia/d/e1rhvX8)

Answer (score 0):

It seems Japanese title is 奥の細道 considering the fact that his novel was named after the Basho's travel diary. Since that translation appears on the [news article](http://digital.asahi.com/articles/DA3S11454327.html), I think it is the commonly agreed title.